# How carry out specific task with multiselect in streamlit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, streamlit

I want to execute one or both operations according to the STREAMLIT multiselect option (specific task) but I can't see what I´m doing wrong. Please, any idea about how to solve it?.

My code:

```
import streamlit as st

calculation = st.multiselect("Select one or both operations:", ('SUM','DIV'))

if calculation =='SUM':st.write(2+2)

elif calculation =='DIV':st.write(10/2)
```

Answer (score 3):

`st.multiselect` returns an array with the selected options

```
import streamlit as st

calculation = st.multiselect("Select one or both operations:", ('SUM','DIV'))

if 'SUM' in calculation:
    st.write(2+2)

if 'DIV' in calculation:
    st.write(10/2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan R.!